# Rotate 2D Sprite with Virtual Joystick

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, joystick

I am trying to rotate a GameObject along z-axis using Joystick, but its rotating y-axis. I might missed some math calculation. Any Help??
Reference Image [image]

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // get input from joystick
        // get input from joystick
        rightJoystickInput = rightJoystick.GetInputDirection();

        float xMovementRightJoystick = rightJoystickInput.x; // The horizontal movement from joystick 02
        float zMovementRightJoystick = rightJoystickInput.y; // The vertical movement from joystick 02


        // if there is only input from the right joystick
        if (rightJoystickInput != Vector3.zero)
        {
            // calculate the player's direction based on angle
            float tempAngle = Mathf.Atan2(zMovementRightJoystick, xMovementRightJoystick);
            xMovementRightJoystick *= Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Cos(tempAngle));
            zMovementRightJoystick *= Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(tempAngle));

            // rotate the player to face the direction of input
            Vector3 temp = transform.position;
            temp.x += xMovementRightJoystick;
            temp.z += zMovementRightJoystick;
            Vector3 lookDirection = temp - transform.position;
            if (lookDirection != Vector3.zero)
            {
                rotationTarget.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rotationTarget.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDirection) * Quaternion.Euler(0, 45f, 0), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've seen this question before and the reason it wasn't answer is because it's not clear what exactly you're doing. You mean to rotate the player to the opposite direction facing x or -x with the joystick? Any visual or video example would be useful

Comment: I updated the question with Reference Image.   @Programmer

Comment: Without knowing 100% what it does, have you tried multiplying with `Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 45f)` instead of `Quaternion.Euler(0, 45f, 0)` ? :)

Comment: I tried to change Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 45f) but after doing this the Player car is freaking out like hell, i mean every values of position and rotations are changing - @WouterHuysentruit

Comment: And FYI, This code is not written by me, its a plugin from Unity Store for 3D Character not 2D. I was just trying to make it work for 2D.

Comment: the script i posted, i was getting smoth rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need most of the code in your question and this is really simple.

**1**.Find the angle with `Mathf.Atan2` then multiple it with `Mathf.Rad2Deg`.

**2**.Use `Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle))` to get the rotation then apply it to the Object.

This should be one in the `Update` function not `FixedUpdate` because `FixedUpdate` is used to move `Rigidbody` Objects.

```
public Transform rotationTarget;
public bool flipRot = true;

void Update()
{
    rightJoystickInput = rightJoystick.GetInputDirection();

    float horizontal = rightJoystickInput.x;
    float vertical = rightJoystickInput.y;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(horizontal, vertical) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    angle = flipRot ? -angle : angle;

    rotationTarget.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
}
```

---

If using `Rigidbody2D` then use `Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation` in the `FixedUpdate` function. The rest of the code stays the-same.

```
public Rigidbody2D rg2d;
public bool flipRot = true;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rightJoystickInput = rightJoystick.GetInputDirection();

    float horizontal = rightJoystickInput.x;
    float vertical = rightJoystickInput.y;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(horizontal, vertical) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    angle = flipRot ? -angle : angle;

    rg2d.MoveRotation(angle);
}
```

**EDIT**:

> But only the problem is when i leave joystick its rotation is setting
>   to 0 instantly which looks too odd. How can i fix it?

You have to detect when you release the joystick in `OnPointerUp` then slowly lerp the joystick thump back to the Zero position. You also have to lerp the current target object angle to zero or to its default value and this should be done in a coroutine function. When `OnPointerDown` is called, stop the current coroutine function. Prevent the code in `FixedUpdate` from running when finger is released so that it won't interfere with the coroutine function.

For the sake of completeness, below is the combination of a Joystick code and the Rigidbody answer above:

```
public class VirtualJoystickController : MonoBehaviour,
    IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    private Image bgImg;
    private Image joystickImg;
    public float mas_distance = 7f;

    void Start()
    {
        bgImg = GameObject.Find("JoystickBGImage").GetComponent<Image>(); // the joysticks background
        joystickImg = GameObject.Find("Joystickthumb").GetComponent<Image>(); // the joystick object to use
    }

    private Vector3 _inputDirection = Vector3.zero;

    //the movementDirection
    public Vector3 joystickInputDirection
    {
        set
        {
            //Change only if value is different from old one
            if (_inputDirection != value)
            {
                _inputDirection = value;

                Debug.Log("Dir: " + _inputDirection);
            }
        }

        get
        {
            return _inputDirection;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        dragJoyStick(eventData);
    }

    void dragJoyStick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 tempDir = Vector3.zero;

        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle
            (bgImg.rectTransform,
            eventData.position,
            eventData.pressEventCamera,
            out pos))
        {

            pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

            float x = (bgImg.rectTransform.pivot.x == 1) ? pos.x * 2 + 1 : pos.x * 2 - 1;
            float y = (bgImg.rectTransform.pivot.y == 1) ? pos.y * 2 + 1 : pos.y * 2 - 1;

            tempDir = new Vector3(x, y, 0);

            if (tempDir.magnitude > 1)
            {
                tempDir = tempDir.normalized;
            }

            joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(
              tempDir.x * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / mas_distance),
                tempDir.y * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / mas_distance));

            joystickInputDirection = tempDir;
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        released = false;
        //Stop current coroutine
        if (retCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(retCoroutine);

        if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject == bgImg.gameObject ||
          eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject == joystickImg.gameObject)
        {
            OnDrag(eventData);
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        released = true;

        //Stop current coroutine then start a new one
        if (retCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(retCoroutine);
        retCoroutine = StartCoroutine(SlowReturn(returnTime));
    }

    IEnumerator SlowReturn(float duration)
    {
        RectTransform thumbstickTransform = joystickImg.rectTransform;

        Vector3 toPosition = Vector3.zero;
        float counter = 0;

        //Get the current position of the object to be moved
        Vector2 currentThumb = thumbstickTransform.anchoredPosition;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;

            //Slowly returns thumbstick
            Vector2 tempThumbStickVal = Vector2.Lerp(currentThumb, toPosition, counter / duration);
            joystickInputDirection = tempThumbStickVal;
            thumbstickTransform.anchoredPosition = tempThumbStickVal;

            //Slowly returns the target Object to original pos
            float tempTargetObjAngle = Mathf.Lerp(angle, originalAngle, counter / duration);
            rg2d.MoveRotation(tempTargetObjAngle);

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public float returnTime = 1.0f;
    public Rigidbody2D rg2d;
    public bool flipRot = true;
    const float originalAngle = 0;
    bool released = true;
    float angle;
    Coroutine retCoroutine;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (released)
            return;

        float horizontal = joystickInputDirection.x;
        float vertical = joystickInputDirection.y;

        angle = Mathf.Atan2(horizontal, vertical) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        angle = flipRot ? -angle : angle;

        rg2d.MoveRotation(angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh very nice, it worked, But only the problem is when i leave joystick its rotation is setting to 0 instantly which looks too odd. How can i fix it? @Programmer

Comment: Check my edit. If you have a new unrelated issue please create a new question.

Comment: Did you see the EDIT?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and a problem was there that is i dont wanted joystick to return to center slowly, SO i fixed it already but i am not getting smoth rotation. @Programmer

Comment: All you had to do was remove the code under the *"//Slowly returns thumbstick"* section but leave the one under the *"//Slowly returns the target Object to original pos"*. This is a very simple thing to do.

Comment: Correct, I did the same. I told you I already fixed that issue. but I am talking about Smooth Rotation when I slide joystick it should slerp the rotation but its rotating with joystick.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to rotate with the joystick? That was the main goal? Rotate Object with joystick? You said it was returning instantly then it was fixed now you're saying it's rotating with the joystick?

Comment: All I am saying is Smooth Rotation is not happening. And I am trying to fix it using Slerp.

Answer (score 0):

your function calculates a point where you want to look at:

```
Vector3 temp = transform.position;
temp.x += xMovementRightJoystick;
temp.z += zMovementRightJoystick;
Vector3 lookDirection = temp - transform.position;
```

this point is on the XZ plane, that is why the car rotates on Y axis

if you want to rotate on Z axis, calculate a point on XY plane like this:

```
Vector3 temp = transform.position;
temp.x += xMovementRightJoystick;
temp.y += zMovementRightJoystick;
Vector3 lookDirection = temp - transform.position;
```

PS: i don't know why you multiply with Quaternion.Euler(0, 45f, 0) - that is a constant angle on Y axis, it just means that each lookDirection will be rotated for 45 degrees - i would have to see your scene to know why you need this...